# Google Play Games failed to sign in

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to configure my application with Google Play Game Services. I have followed the documentation and instruction carefully,added it to the console and linked it with the SHA1 fingerprint certificate.

Here's my code:

```
public void performInteractiveSignIn() {
    Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            //The signed in account is stored in the result
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
        } else {
            String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
            Toast.makeText(this, result.getStatus().getStatusMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

however I always seem to get the error 4: 4: despite adding the OAuth2 Client ID. 
App Id is also linked onto the Manifest.xml. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Is the resolution in this [reported issue](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1834#issuecomment-316750925), helps you fix it?

Comment: not really, actually the error was in the Google play console. I had not added my email address as a tester